# Creating separate timer for speed and ball creating

Tags: c++, qt, qtimer

I am working on Falling ball application,
About the application: the balls keep on falling at regular intervals, and there is a basket that catches the balls. If caught then we earn a point if not then lose one life.

For this application, I am using qt and CPP.
I have created one class Sprite with specifications regarding the initial position of the ball(x and y) and speed (dx and dy).
I am using one timer for the speed of the ball, but I need to another timer for ball creation at regular intervals. Could anyone help me with how to implement the ball creation at regular intervals?

```
sprite.h
--------
#ifndef SPRITE_H
#define SPRITE_H

#include <QTimer>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QWidget>

/**
 * Header class for Sprite
 */
class Sprite : public QTimer
{
public:
    Sprite(QWidget *parent);
    //draw() to draw a sprite
    void draw(QPainter &painter);
protected:
    //This timerEvent will be called after certain time prescribed.
    virtual void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *e) override;

    int x;//position of sprite in x-direction.
    int y;//position of sprite in y-direction.
    int dx;//difference in x-direction position.
    int dy;//difference in y-direction position.
    int x1;//position of the basket in x-direction
    int y1;//position of the basket in y-direction.
    QWidget *parent;//parent class for all widgets.

};
#endif // SPRITE_H


sprite.cpp
-----------
#include "sprite.h"
#include <QDebug>

Sprite::Sprite(QWidget *parent):parent(parent)
{
    QRect rct = parent->rect();
    x = rand() % rct.width();//randomly initialize the x-position for the sprite.
    y=rct.height()*0.05;//start position for the sprite is about 5% after the top of the menu bar.

    dx = rand() % 10;//the speed is randomly set in x-direction.

//    dy = rand() % 10;//the speed is randomly set in y-direction.
    dy = 4;

    x1=rct.width()/2;
    y1 = rct.height()-80;

    start(10);

}

void Sprite::draw(QPainter &painter)
{
    qDebug() <<"Sprite::draw() called";
    painter.drawEllipse(x, y, 15, 15);//ball
    painter.drawRect( x1, y1, 80, 30);//basket
}


void Sprite::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *)
{
    qDebug("timerEvent called");
    QRect rct = parent->rect();
    if ( x > rct.width() || x < 0)
        dx *= -1;
    if ( y > rct.height() || y < 0){}

    x += dx;
    y += dy;
    parent->update();
}

mainwindow.cpp
-----------------
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QKeyEvent>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    qDebug() <<"mainWindow constructor";

      QTimer timer;
    QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, this,&MainWindow::onTimer);
    timer.start(1000);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    qDebug() <<"mainWindow destructor";
    delete ui;
}
void MainWindow::onTimer()
{
    std::cout << "Tick!-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;

}
  


void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    qDebug() <<"painEvent() called";
    QPainter painter(this);

    painter.fillRect(rect(), QBrush(QColor(Qt::white)));

    painter.setPen(Qt::black);
    painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(Qt::darkBlue)));
    emit draw(painter);
}
    
MainWindow.h
-----------
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "sprite.h"
#include <balls.h>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow

{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
signals:
    void draw(QPainter &painter);
    void move(int nDirection);

protected:
    //This event handler captures all the paint events request to repaint all or part of the widget.
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)override;
    
public slots:
    void onTimer();

private slots:
    void on_actionStart_triggered();

    void on_actionStop_triggered();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Sprite *sprite;
    };
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

How can I create balls at regular intervals, any sudo code will help.

Or any better way to implement this is also welcome.

Comment: If you already know how to create a timer for the ball speed, can't you just duplicate that but have it call a Drop Another Ball function when it fires?

Comment: Iam  using timerEvent() to generate speed for the timer, If I use an another function then how can I call that function at regular intervals?

Comment: Take whatever you're doing to create the timerEvent() and duplicate it.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to qt and cpp, I am using  Spring class timer for speed and it fires at 10 ms. But I need a new ball creation at each 2000ms. These two are separate time intervals. Could you suggest some sudo code

Comment: If I were writing this, I would just have the 10mS timer-slot increment an integer counter, and when the counter got up to 200, I'd create a ball and reset the counter back to zero.  That way only a single timer is needed.

Comment: In general, don't use timer event, create QTimer objects. There's no measurable benefit using events.

Comment: @hyde Could you please suggest some better way of implementing this game

Comment: @SyedIftekharuddin Just use QTimers instead of timerEvent. What do you mean?

Comment: A general note about asking questions: try to create a [mcve], this question is about timer, everything else such as the actual painting code is irrelevant for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Calling [`QObject::startTimer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#startTimer) twice, will run two timers simultaneously:

```
int timerId1 = startTimer(2000);
int timerId2 = startTimer(10);

void MyObject::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event)
{
    if (event->timerId() == timerId1)
        ; // 2000ms timer is fired
     else if (event->timerId() == timerId2)
        ; // 10ms timer is fired
}
```

Also the [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#startTimer) itself contains a clear example of this use case.

An alternative is to use two [`QTimer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html) objects, and connect a slot to the `timeout` signal of each `QTimer` object.

Comment: I used another slot onTimer but its never call by the timer on timeout. I mentioned this in the above code

Comment: @SyedIftekharuddin The `QTimer` defined in your `MainWindow` constructor is scoped locally and will be destroyed when the constructor completes.  That's why `onTimer` is never called.